# onclick redirect to other page and open hidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 5 buttons in the home page and 5 hidden divs on a contact page. If I click on button 1 then it should redirect to the contact page and open hidden div 1, button 2 does the same but opens 2.

So my div

```
<div id="button1">
   <a href="/contact/#div1">
```

I have tried this `$( "#div1" ).trigger( "click" );` it does redirect to the other page but it opens all divs instead of just that 1

Comment: Please add your js code to the question.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: as Stefano said, the best option its add a parameter in the href attribute where you says which div should open, and in the onready of the contact page, make taht div visible.

Answer (score 0):

i can only suggest you to pass in the url-string-GET the number of the div.. then parse it in javascript..